# Reading bucket of elements from RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, file-io, datainputstream, randomaccessfile

I have a `RandomAccessFile` and I want to read fixed sized buckets of ints from this file, but each of them starts at different locations. What I am doing is creating a `new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(rfile2.getFD()), bucketSize))` and before reading the bucket, I use rfile2.seek(startPosition). Then I get the elements by using `DataInputStream`'s method `Readint`.

Is this a correct approach? Would using `FileInputStream`'s method `read` make it faster?